# If a DAG ran successfully how do you run an Airflow backfill from command line?

Tags: airflow

I have a DAG that runs daily that I've done some changes to and I need to rerun it for several months.

If I go to the Airflow UI I can clear and it will run, but that's a lot of clicking. Is there another way to do this?  if I do the backfill from the command line like this:

```
airflow backfill -s 20200101 -e 20200301 daily_dag_name
```

This won't actually run the dag, I believe that's because it ran successfully and the backfill only works if it failed.

Comment: how about `clear` command?   https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.1/cli.html#clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are already DAG runs for the execution dates, there is nothing to backfill. What you need is to clear those DAG runs that will re-trigger the runs for the given time period:

```
airflow tasks clear -s 20200101 -e 20200301 daily_dag_name
```